# Cmd+plus now opens Widgets instead of zooming

Tags: keyboard, google-chrome, dashboard-widget, zoom

This has just started happening in the last few weeks, and I can't work out how to change it.

It used to be that I could use Cmd+= to zoom in in my web browser, and cmd+- to zoom out. But just recently, that has been overridden so that it opens Widgets settings. It's also odd because there are all these (x) buttons to close widgets (presumably) but there is nothing there apart from the buttons.

Anyone know how to change that shortcut so I can zoom in my browser again?

Comment: It opens Dashboard and then the row of widgets that can be added?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix it by unchecking "Show Dashboard as a space" in Mission Control Preferences. No idea when exactly this change happened or why this fixes it though. [image: Preferences Pane for Mission Control]

I would have preferred to be able to just re-map the shortcut, but I can't find it anywhere.