# How to zoom with cmd+mouse wheel in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, zoom

I used to zoom in Chrome on Linux by holding Control and scrolling with the mouse wheel. Now on Mac when I press Cmd and scroll it just scrolls.

How can I get Cmd+scroll zoom on Mac?

Comment: see also http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/103972/zooming-in-google-chrome-using-the-mouse-wheel and http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/83202/cmdplus-now-opens-widgets-instead-of-zooming

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't answer my question - how to zoom pages in Chrome with Cmd+scroll

Comment: Did you run any upgrades or other changes since the last time you could scroll with Cmd-Scroll?

Comment: To be honest, I can't say for sure. There are always some updates in Chrome. I can't even say it used to work on Mac - but I do know it works on Linux/Windows. I changed my question to reflect this.

Comment: Just checked on another Mac, it doesn't work as well.

Comment: Then how is your situation different from http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/103972/zooming-in-google-chrome-using-the-mouse-wheel (which also offers a solution)?

Comment: Because that extensions doesn't allow to zoom with cmd+wheel. It adds a magnifying glass to the top-right of the page and zoom works if you scroll on that icon. Control+wheel also does't work - it zooms _screen_, not _page_.

Comment: Hey, this question doesn't have an answer in that topic!

Comment: The question referred to at the top of your question now focuses exactly on the same problem. I'm aware of the fact that the answers presented don't take care of the "Cmd" part but that's basically just not possible on OS X (at least not with some other drawbacks).